# Woher kommt "Ene Mene"?

Tags: etymology, baby-talk

In Kinderreimen findet sich häufig die Lautkombination *"Ene Mene"* oder *"Ende dene"*, so wie in dem bekanntesten Abzählreim:

> Ene Mene Muh und raus bist Du

Im Schwäbischen gibt es einen Abzählreim, dessen sprachliche Wurzel sich mir überhaupt nicht erschließt:

> Ene mene dubbe dene
>
> Duppe dene dalia
>
> Ebbe be[a]bbe bembio
>
> Bio bio buff!

Gibt es eine Theorie aus welcher Sprache sich dieser Reim herleitet? Was könnte dieser Reim bedeuten?

Comment: Irgendwie mit dem engl. _eenie meenie miney mo_ verwandt?

Comment: „Ene Mene Miste, es rappelt in der Kiste, Ene Mene Muh und raus bist du! Raus bist du noch lange lange nicht, sag mir erst wie alt du bist! Eins, Zwei, Drei, Vier, …“

Comment: Die schwäbische Version ist echt hart. ^^

Comment: Im sächsichen würde man hinter "Ene mene" einfach "eine, meine" vermuten.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Habe eine [ähnliche Diskussion](http://www.wer-weiss-was.de/theme197/article3869948.html) gefunden und darin diesen netten Ansatz:

> ich vermute, dass viele dieser Abzählreime ebenso wie z.B. Zaubersprüche eine Ableitung oder Nachahmung liturgischer Texte sind.
>   Die waren - weil in Latein - ja dem gemeinen Volke ebenso unverständlich.
>   Durch die rein mündliche Überlieferung sind sie noch weiter entstellt und regional angepasst worden.

Und dabei ist mir gerade aufgefallen, dass mich "Ene Mene" ganz stark an [eine Bibelstelle](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Menetekel) erinnert:

> Mene mene tekel u-parsin

Was derselbe Autor dann zwei Seiten weiter auch vermutet:

> Die Schrift an der Wand, die die Gelehrten nicht deuten konnten, lautete "Mene tekel upharsin". *Daniel dagegen interpretiert das Orakel mit Hilfe ähnlich klingender aramäischer Verben: gezählt, gewogen und geteilt [Wikipedia]*
>   Und da es sich ja um einen Abzählreim handelt, kommt der Gleichklang vielleicht nicht ganz so zufällig.

Vgl. dazu auch [Hokus Pokus](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hokuspokus).

Answer (score 2):

In der englischen Wikipedia findet sich ein Eintrag zu [Eeny, meeny, miny, moe](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eeny,_meeny,_miny,_moe#Origins).

Eine der Theorien zu dessen Herkunft ist ein [Zählsystem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yan_Tan_Tethera), mit dem Schäfer ihre Schafe zählen konnten.

Comment: "The rhyme seems to have been unknown in England among collectors until the late nineteenth century, although it was found by Henry Bolton in the USA, Ireland and Scotland in the 1880s." ...hmh, dann könnten es genauso gut die deutschen Einwanderer mitgebracht haben. :)