# Grüß dich, Grüezi wohl und Grüß Gott

Tags: etymology, phrase, morphology

Statt in einer zehn Jahre alten Kommentarspalte zu mutmaßen, frage ich lieber nach. Ausgangspunkt ist diese Aussage

> [*...*] was weit weniger sinnvoll wäre. (Aber was heißt schon sinnvoll, wir sagen ja auch ***Grüß Gott***.) – sgf [Feb 3 '17 at 11:10](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/254/woher-kommt-pfiat-di-pfiat-eich-als-abschiedsformel-im-bayerischen-raum#comment85846_260)

Mein Einwurf dazu: Komisch, ich höre öfters *Grüß Dich!*.

Wenn man eins und eins zusammenzählt, liegt doch die Vermutung nahe, der einen Grußformel kam ein Pronomen abhanden, der anderen das Subjekt.

Nun habe ich erhebliche Zweifel daran und die vordergründige Frage drängt sich auf, ob wenigstens einer der Ausdrücke auf eine ganz andere, anderweitig verschollene Verbform zurückgeht.

Der Imperativ, der bei *Grüß Gott!* wohl allgemein unterstellt wird, sei mal dahingestellt. Bei *Grüß Dich* oder *Grüezi mitenand* usw. funktioniert imperativ eher nicht. Nun zweifle ich, ob wie bei *pfiat enk* (siehe das oben verlinkte Thema, sowie auch [jene Antwort](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/44889/35977)) in formulhafter Kontraktion eine archaische Sprachstufe ganz ungrammatisch konserviert werden konnte, das auch hier der Fall sein kann. Leider kenne ich mich mit archaischen Sprachstufen und Dialekten wirklich nicht aus (diachroneische Dialektologie).

Ein Beispiel zu Vergleichen sei genannt: *Lass' los gehen*; Das ist m.M.n. womöglich ein alter Optativ o.ä (vgl. *Grüß, lass*, wie *greet, let*). Das ist unglaublich schwierig zu begreifen, sobald Modus, Stimme und Aspekt gleichzeitig infrage stehen, die meinetwegen auch schon voreinzelsprachlich verknöchert worden sein hätten können. Mein Ansatz lautet soweit *grüszdich* < **gruszit-enk < ... mit Plattdeutschem Lenis des Velars (vgl. Limburgisch dual och plural: [öch](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/doe#Limburgish)) oder direkt von 2.Dual.Imp. [*grōtijaþiz](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Reconstruction:Proto-Germanic/gr%C5%8Dtijan%C4%85) (vgl. Berliner akkusativ *dir*); tut zwar nichts zur Sache, deutet aber an, wo die Reise hi gehen soll, vorbei an Grimm, Adelung und oberpfälzischen Kanzleideutsch direkt ob die wichtigen theoretischen Fragen.

Ich bitte also um Verweise auf eine wissenschaftliche Untersuchung zum Thema anhand landläufiger Archaismen mit der entsprechenden Wurzel.

Übrigens sieht man auch allerlei Anpassungsversuche, die auszusortieren einer Auflösung im Wege stehen, bspw. *ich grüße Sie*, sowie in Abschiedsformeln. Derlei klingt für mich dann aber wieder nach Imperativ.

---

Grüße

Vectory!

**PS:** Die nachrangige Frage verbleibt, wie eine eventuelle Verkürzung zu *Grüß Gott* zu erklären wäre, bzw. wie der Modus usw. usf. zu deuten sind, falls, wie ich meine, Zweifel an einem ursprünglichen Pronomen bestehen.

**PPS:** Nach kurzer Lesung des bei [Grimm: *grüszen*](https://www.dwds.de/wb/dwb/Gr%C3%BCszen) äußerst absurd dargestellten Bedeutungswandels wird schnell klar, dass die Zurückführung auf Urgermanisch wenig Überzeugungskraft hat--um so wichtiger ein Verständnis der Grußformellen. Denn es ist doch absurd, dass eine Grundbedeutung "to sound" (en.wiktionary: *ǵʰreh₁d-) angesetzt wird, während *gʷerH- "to welcome, express approval; praise" (vgl. Latein *gratia* "thanks", Sanskrit *gūrdhayā, “to praise”, etc.; cf. "*schlieszlich kann sich die bedeutung 'zu etwas gratulieren' ergeben.*" oben bei Grimme), bzw. *werh₁- "to speak" quasi sinngleich vorliegen, der Unterschied im Anlaut durch Lehnbeziehungen auf unbestimmte Zeit vermutet werden kann, worin ggf. das Grammatikproblem neu zu ergründen wäre. Keine weiteren Fragen.

**P³S:**: Nochmal zu der Lautnachahmung. Es finden sich zumindest vier relativ ähnliche Wurzeln, die zu vergleichen naheliegt, weil Onomatopoeia ggf. irregulär sind, der Unterschied also bums wie wums ist. Nämlich (i) eben zu *grüßen* (ii) eben zu*gratia* (iii) zu *Krähe, Kranich, krähen, krächzen*, vielleicht *krakelen*, etc. (iiii) zu *Rabe*, Lat. *corvus*. Dabei soll *corvus* < *ḱer- möglicher Weise nicht unbedingt nachahmend sein (vgl. en.wiktionary: corvus, daneben dwds.de: Rabe zwar ja nachahmend doch unsicher ob zu corvus; das mag dahinstehen). Daneben steht eine unsegliche Liste weiterer Schallnachahmungen angesetzt, teils aufeinander verweisend, teils auf andere Wurzeln (s. [Sound](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/semantic/field/SP_SO) in utexas' PIE Lexicon, durchnummeriert ebenda nach [Pokorny PIE Master Etyma](https://lrc.la.utexas.edu/lex/master#P2874), d. i. (i) #439 *gher- (ii) #478 gu̯er(ə)- (iii) #383-85 *ger (iiii) ebenso, aber s. oben).

Bemerkenswert fand ich *krähen* nun deshalb, weil Douglas Harper die spezifische Bedeutung des Hahnenschreis im Deutschen sowie auch Niederländisch *kraaijen* in Bezug nimmt (etymonline.com: *crow (v)*). Denn der Hahn läutet mit seinem Gruß bekanntlich den Morgen ein. Zudem steht die Redewendung "da kräht kein Hahn nach" den bei Grimm bzw. im EWA Bedeutungen nahegelegten Bedeutungen in nichts nach (s. MHD grüezen "anreden, ansprechen, grüßen, auf-, herausfordern, antreiben, hetzen, beunruhigen, angreifen", Etymologisches Wörterbuch des Althochdeutschen: gruozen).

Allerdings sagt der Hahn nicht *kräh-kräh*, doch *kikeriki*, bzw. En. *cock-a-doodle-doo*, u.s.w.. Und so fort könnte man bspw. *-riki-* zu *rectus* plus *hi', hier* oder Plattdeutsch *jie* "ihr" stellen, wie auch Englisch signifikante Wortformen erkennen lässt, um es so zu lesen *steht auf* zu deuten. Doch natürlich ist das wegen möglicher Variationen ebenso schwer zu fassen wie [Ene Mene](https://german.stackexchange.com/questions/1110/woher-kommt-ene-mene) Abzählreime, die schlicht als Nonsense aufgefasst werden. Zu einer Antwort führt diese Deutung deshalb vielleicht nicht. Die Tragweite des Problems muss zur Grundlegung der Fragd aber deutlich umrissen werden, da es mithin um Univerbation und Volksetymologie zu gehen scheint. Der Vergleich könnte dennoch goldrichtig sein, weil es je Wurzel, insbesondere *Hre'g- (daher *(auf)richten*) einer Herleitung innerer Ableitung bedarf.

Damit solcher Buchstabensalat im Kontext der Seite funktioniert, ist zwingende Vorraussetzung, dass alle Vergleiche auch innerdeutsch funktionabel sind. Dass die Bedeutung "jagen" m. M. n. nicht direkt zum Thema gehört, das glaube ich unterdess fast nicht, da *vergrätzen* "verjagen, unbeliebt machen" dem näher steht, aber auch *vergraueln*, *grantig*, ugs. *ätzend*, etc. Dafür ist anzusetzen, dass die Schreibung der Wortstämme, die in archaischer Rechtschreibung sicherlich divers war, nach lexikografischer Normalisierung nicht mehr unterscheidbar sind.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/126615/discussion-on-question-by-vectory-gruss-dich-gruezi-wohl-und-gruss-gott).

Comment: Recht so, @guidot. Will aber noch mal anmerken daß die Grundannahme "Grüß Gott" sei ein Imperativ nicht zutrifft, es ist eine verkürzte Form des Konjunktiv Präsenz (auch: Optativ) und aus "Es grüße dich Gott" oder "Gott grüße dich" abgeleitet, grüßen in einer Bedeutung von "segnen". Der Gruß und seine Varianten ist alltäglich im südlichen deutschen Sprachraum.

Comment: @a_donda, schau, deine Aussage «"Grüß Gott" sei ein Imperativ» ist schon hübsch Konjunktiv, aber die Aussage hinreichend irrelefant. Schließlich ging es um "archaische Formen". Die Bedeutung--darum geht es hier letztendlich--die du mit "segnen" anführst, ergibt sich schlimmestenfalls aus der Phrase selbst, denkbar eine noch längere Phrase. Mir schwant übles, vgl. *kennen Sie schon unsern Herr und ...* oder ähnliches. So, jemand der *Sei gegrüßt*, *Sei mir gegrüßt* benützt, hat niemanden gesegnet oder heilig gesprochen, vermutlich auch nicht Gott außer Acht gelassen, sonder einfach eine Floskel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nach umfangreicher Recherche lässt sich keine solche Untersuchung finden. Die Frage ist also leider mit "Nein, es gibt keine Verweise auf solche wiss. Untersuchungen" zu beantworten.